# Can't move tabs in Chrome

Tags: unity, google-chrome

When I try to move tabs in Chrome they always open in a new window and can't be moved back to old window.

Using latest Chrome from official repository.
Worked fine before with GNOME.

Any ideas how to fix, apart from going back to GNOME?

Answer: this is a [long-running bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/935713), which has recently (January 2022) re-occurred for some users.

Comment: This bug you are experiencing has already been documented as a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/935713). If you have queries, please post comments in the bug report. I am now proceeding to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for pointer to bug report. If there was no bug report would this type of question be considered off topic?

Comment: We tend not to entertain questions that are bugs. See [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/226/are-bug-reports-suitable-for-this-site) for the discussion.

Comment: This question, if edited, would make sense, and there are workarounds that would make sense to have as answers.
For one, you can move tabs if the window is not maximized.

Comment: 7 years later and this bug still appears unresolved...

Comment: Almost 8 years now...

Comment: Getting close to 9 years...

Comment: it's 12 years now, experiencing it for some time now.

Comment: I had not experienced this in some time, then today's Ubuntu software update brought the breakage back for me. 2c: this should be left open, with an acceptable answer, as it is effectively a long-running FAQ.